# Living organisms are not at equilibrium with their surroundings

Tags: biochemistry

Why the living organisms can never be at equilibrium with their surroundings?

Comment: What is a living system? How would you define it?

Comment: Hi hafiz, the current question seems a bit unclear. Additional context,  like from which book you got this question, relevant text around it, etc.  would help. Also, please also show an attempt to understand the problem, like: what did you understand from it, and how did you think of solving it? Thanks, and welcome to Chem.SE!

Comment: I got this from the Lehninger principles of biochemistry while studying the bioenergetics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being at equilibrium with your surroundings means that for everything (particles, chemicals, energy) that comes inside you from your surroundings an equivalent amount of it is returned to the environment, unaltered (same structure, same energy, same concentration, etc.). At the same time, and in the same manner, anything going out to the environment will be returned to you. You will not change your environment. 
.
Equilibrium works both ways, so the envirionment will not change you, either.
.
If you are alive, this cannot keep up for long. You will need to use your stored energy (can't get it from your environment if you are at equilibrium with it) for your basic functions as a live being. Part of this energy will invariably become waste heat energy which you must get out of your body or you will heat up too much and die. But if you are at equilibrium with your environment, you cannot get rid of it. So...
.
But perhaps you are spore-like, and completely inactive (not even an inner timer)? Then one of two things may happen: you cannot receive anything from the environment, or you can. If you can't, you will never be able to get something to revive you. If you can, you will receive something, and then you are not in equilibrium with your environment.

Comment: It isn't just about transport into or out of the cell. Even expending "stored energy" leads to changes in concentrations of the concerned species - this, too, cannot happen in an equilibrium condition.
A cell at equilibrium is a dead cell.